# Can I redirect to a specific IP Address depending on the incoming port via DNS on Cloudflare?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I basically want to send port 443 to my github pages site and port 25565 to my minecraft server. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in some specific cases, but not in general. Minecraft is one of the few cases where it could be done.

Regular A/AAAA record DNS lookups are made *long before* the port comes into play – the DNS server doesn't know what kind of connection will be made to the domain. Only *some* programs make some kind of service-specific DNS lookup. For example, Minecraft supports `_minecraft` SRV records that redirect it to a different domain name (and possibly port). ([Example.](https://www.meloncube.net/clients/knowledgebase/137/How-to-Add-an-SRV-record-for-Minecraft-using-cPanel.html))

(In other words, it isn't "`domain:port → address`", it's more like "`domain → address:port`", even when SRV is in use.)

Currently web browsers don't support anything like that, so the main A/AAAA records must still point to your web server. (In the future, they might add support for SVCB – which is like SRV except newer and overcomplicated.)

For programs that don't do SRV/SVCB, the easiest workaround is to just create a subdomain (which will have its own A/AAAA records). For example, if Minecraft didn't support SRV, you'd have to use `mc.example.com` or something similar. That's what subdomains are for.

Comment: yeah. I kinda didn't want to create a subdomain for it, but if it doesn't work any other way, I'll just do that. Thank you for your answer anyways. :D